# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'formatDate')

Tags: jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

What's the problem in my code?

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'formatDate')

```
 editable:true,
    eventResize:function(event)
    {
    console.log(event.start);
    
     var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
     var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
     var title = event.title;
     var id = event.id;
     $.ajax({
      url:"../Components/calendar/update.php",
      type:"POST",
      data:{title:title, start:start, end:end, id:id},
      success:function(){
       calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
       alert('Event Update');
      }
     })
    }
```

Console.log of event.start

[image]

Comment: Your question/issue doesn't seem to be related to PHP, so please remove that tag.

Comment: `$.fullCalendar` doesn't exist at the time your code runs - did you miss a `<script src=`?

Comment: i dont think so

Comment: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

Comment: Then check the console for errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is old version

```
$.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```

Solution:

```
moment(event.start, 'DD.MM.YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

When You select the start and end date on full calendar use following code as well:

```
select: function(start, end) {
                  
     var start_date = moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
     var end_date = moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
```